# Why Senders are not getting approved in Moosend?

Tags: moosend

I am working on the trial version of the Sitecore Moosend platform, where I signed up with my organization's email address. As part of the initial set-up, I am adding a new sender. But all the senders are getting rejected. I've tried adding sender with the `moosend.com` domain as well as my professional email address.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add a new Sender an email is send to the mail you set it up to confirm the sender.

[image]

After you confirm the email on the Moosend dashboard you will see:

[image]

Did you get confirmation mail ? I used gmail accounts and it works fine. Maybe on your business email you have some special security rules

**Update**

Raman wrote to Moosend support and he receive next answer:  We have many checkers that run once you add a sender so one of them was stopping it - but i manually checked it, saw that it was okay and accepted it for you!

If you have similar issue write to Moosend support

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've even tried with my Gmail email id but not getting any confirmation email. I've already checked the spam/quartine folder of both of my mailboxes (Gmail and professional).

Comment: weird, I have a demo Moosend account and it works with both emails which I added.

Answer (score 3):

When a user creates a new sender, we automatically check the name of the sender and the email address of the sender.
If our system/services will detect that the user used a domain name that previously has been recorded related to spam activity, we immediately reject the sender.
We follow the same actions when it comes to the sender's name as well.
Our system follows specific rules in order to check a sender and then it will decide if the new sender will be rejected or if it will be accepted we automatically send the verification link as well.
From the screenshot you shared above, i can see that you tried to create a user under moosend.com. We don't allow our users to use our domain name to send campaigns, so that alerted our system or an agent of the compliance department.
However, i would like to investigate this further for you, so you can simple send me a message and let me know the email addresses of the senders you tried to create and i can update you why those emails have been rejected in the first place.

Comment: Hi Sarah, welcome to Sitecore StackExchange. Thanks a lot for replying to this issue. I raised this with Moosend Support and got it resolved. This is the response I got from support: We have many checkers that run once you add a sender so one of them was stopping it - but I manually checked it, saw that it was okay and accepted it for you!